# What is an "active writing style"?

Tags: style

The preface of Introduction to Algorithms mentions that

> In this, the third edition, we have once again updated the entire book. The changes cover a broad spectrum, including new chapters, revised pseudocode, and a more active writing style.

Comment: Could it be used to refer to *active writing voice*, as opposed to a *passive writing voice*? Passive voice would be like this: The meal was served and eaten. Active voice would be like this: The woman served the meal and allowed us to eat.

Comment: In English literature, writers generally favor active voice. In English scientific writing, writers generally favor passive voice. Note I mention English, because some languages may use a formal variety of the language for scientific papers.

Comment: My guess is it is the pedagogical style that is more active. "Active learning strategies" is a thing in educational circles. Check the chapters for more practice boxes, the end of chapters for practice problems, and the book for mention of online interactive content.